# Laravel 5.7 validate fields with asterisk, required_if

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.7

I have a Vue form that let users add work experience for there profile.
Users can add extra experience by clicking on a button. Clicking on that will add an new item with new input fields. I can't add the whole script because it's quit big. But here is an example to give you an idea:

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label class="form-label">Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="experiences[0][title]" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label class="form-label">Institution</label>
            <input type="text" name="experiences[0][institution]" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <textarea name="experiences[0][comments]" class="form-control"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label class="form-label">Title </label>
            <input type="text" name="experiences[1][title]" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label class="form-label">institution </label>
            <input type="text" name="experiences[1][institution]" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <textarea name="experiences[1][comments]" class="form-control"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

After each element there is a button to add a new row. This works fine but I have some validation issues.
I only want to validate the fields if one of the fields has a value. For example:
If `experiences[0][institution]` has a value, `experiences[0][title]` and `experiences[0][comments]` are required. 
This has to work in every order. If `title` has a value, the other fields are required.
I can't really find out a way how to validate this. This is my validation rule:

```
$this->validate(request(), [
        'experiences.*.title'       => 'required_if:experiences.*.institution,null',
        'experiences.*.institution' => 'required_if:experiences.*.title,null',
]);
```

Problem here is that it simply doesn't validate. I can't figure out how to make a rule that says, if field X has a value, Y and Z are required.

Hope anyone here can help me finding a solution! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Azeame said, make a custom validation rule and check if all values are filled or all are empty. Something in de lines of:

```php
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    $required = ['title','institution','comments'];

    $experience = collect($value)->reject(function ($item, $key) {
        return empty($item);
    });

    if (count($experience) == 0) {
        return true;
    }

    foreach ($required as $field) {
        if ( !$experience->has($field)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Maybe there is a beter way, but this should work.

Comment: I will give it a try :)

Answer (score 1):

`required_if` doesn't work with `null` as it will treat it as a string (`"null"`), it will work with boolean values though.

Instead you can use the [required_without](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-required-without) rule:

```
$this->validate(request(), [
    "experiences.*.title"       => "required_without:experiences.*.institution",
    "experiences.*.institution" => "required_without:experiences.*.title",
]);
```

---

Example

```
$experiences = [
    [
        "title"       => "My title",
        "institution" => "",
        "comments"    => "<p>My first description</p>", //passes
    ],
    [
        "title"       => "",
        "institution" => "My title",
        "comments"    => "<p>My second description</p>", //passes
    ],
    [
        "title"       => "My title",
        "institution" => "My title",
        "comments"    => "<p>My third description</p>", //passes
    ],
    [
        "title"       => "",
        "institution" => null,
        "comments"    => "<p>My forth description</p>", //fails
    ],

];

$rules = [
    "experiences.*.title"       => "required_without:experiences.*.institution",
    "experiences.*.institution" => "required_without:experiences.*.title",
];

$validator = Validator::make(compact('experiences'), $rules);

dd($validator->fails());
```

Comment: Somehow it skips the first part of the validation. If I leave `title` empty and give `institution` a value it doesn't validate. But the second part after the `merge`, works great :-)

Comment: @Ruub can you show the output of `dd(request('experiences'))` for your above example?

Comment: `[
  "title"       => null,
  "institution" => "My Company",
  "comments"    => "<p>My first description</p>",
 ],
 [
  "title"       => "My title",
  "institution" => null,
  "comments"    => "<p>My second description</p>",
 ]
];`

Comment: Wait, the exact output is:
`array:2 [
 0 => array:3 [
    "title" => null
    "institution" => "My Company"
    "comments" => "<p>My first description</p>"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [
    "title" => "My title"
    "institution" => null
    "comments" => "<p>My second description</p>"
  ]
]`

Comment: @Ruub Scratch all of that, it's an issue with the rule being used. I'll update my answer now.

Comment: Hmm. Now it doesn't validate if one of the fields has an value. But it does if there are both empty. But that's not really what we are looking for :)

Comment: @Ruub That's very strange as I'm getting the exact opposite. Just so I'm not missing something are you saying that if one of the fields has a value the validation fails and throws an exception but it doesn't if they're both empty?

Answer (score 1):

Write a custom rule with `php artisan make:rule` and in the `passes()` function write a check to ensure that all of the array keys are present and also that at least 2 of the array values are not null.  I'm thinking something like this:

```
function passes($attribute, $value){
    if(array_keys($value) !== ['title','institution','comments']){
        return false;
    }
    if(empty($value['title']) && empty($value['institution'])){
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

and in your `$this->validate` pass the rule as `['experiences.*' =>['array', new CustomRule()]` instead of `required_if...`

I haven't checked this so feel free to edit if it's broken.

Comment: I also had the idea to make a custom rule, but was really hoping there would be a more "easy" way of doing this :)

Comment: It's actually really easy, give it a try, you'll be surprised, if I wasn't in my phone with no WiFi right now I'd just go ahead write it for you now

Comment: @Ruub I updated the answer, see if this will work for you, I believe it should work well

Comment: I will give it a try :)

Comment: Hmm. It returns true because all three fields are present. But it doesn't check if they all have a value.

Comment: How about combining my solution with Ross's, will that cover all the bases?

Comment: I think so yes, I will come back with an update. Thank you guys!

Comment: I edited it again, though I'm not there's actually a benefit in the first if statement, but it's 4:30am and I haven't slept yet, so I left it in for now, you could also replace the empty calls with a comparison to null, need sleep